# How to fix uncaught ReferenceError after upgrading to angular 11

Tags: angular

I've updated an angular application from 10 to 11 and am getting an error

```
main-es5.js?qnqoqf:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
at Module.zUnb (main-es5.js?qnqoqf:1)
```

This error only appears with the packaged program. All tests pass and it runs using the angular cli.

I've tried *npm install regenerator-runtime* with no change.

*ng list* shows that the dependency comes from babel 7.12.5.

```
│ ├─┬ @babel/runtime@7.12.5
│ │ └── regenerator-runtime@0.13.7 deduped
```

I've tried

```
 npm install --save regenerator-runtime
```

and included *import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';* in app.module.ts as per [babel error report](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9849)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a pollyfill, browser compatibility issue.

A clean angular 11 project was created and the *.browserslistrc* file was copied

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

The angular upgrade notes do say that the es2015 compatibility is being dropped. https://blog.angular.io/version-10-of-angular-now-available-78960babd41#c357. It looks like configuration change is required to get it to run.